# Retrieve Data From Database And Store It In A Variable In PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

I want to retrieve the data stored under column `level` in my database which means I want 0 to be stored in a variable.

[image]

This is the code I am using to retrieve the value from the database and store it in a variable called `$level`. But, I get the value as `none`. Where am I going wrong?

```
 $s = $dbh->prepare("SELECT phpro_username FROM phpro_users 
        WHERE phpro_username = $phpro_username");

 $s->execute();

 $level = $s->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: The screenshot here isn't anything helpful, and secondly, **DO NOT** put in arbitrary data like that. Use prepared statements. That's [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) with `mysqli` or the [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) system in PDO.

Comment: Can You Tell Me Exactly How To Do That?

Comment: Can you read the documentation which I linked to? It's very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about prepared statements, but your query is wrong if you're trying to retrieve a value from the "level" column. Try this:

```
$s = $dbh->prepare("SELECT level FROM phpro_users 
        WHERE phpro_username = $phpro_username");

$s->execute();

$level = $s->fetchColumn();
```

Also, if $s->fetchColumn() is returning nothing, then maybe your $phpro_username variable doesn't contain a valid username.